# Make a standalone OpenCV application using QMake

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator, qmake, static-linking

I was using the OpenCV library to make a console application in Qt Creator *(I'm just using QMake and the IDE, not any of the Qt libraries)*.  This is on Ubuntu.

First I was using OpenCV dynamically (using an .so)  But I want to execute my application on PCs that don't have OpenCV installed.  So I'm trying to make a standalone executable:

- I recompile and install OpenCV statically (by using the parameter `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` )
- I tried adding `CONFIG += staticlib` on my project.pro but I had remarked that it's still using the dynamic library
- I tried to compile on profile/debug/release but none of these build options give me the good result
- I finally tried to add `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static` and recopied the line on opencv.pc:

> LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_ts -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_photo -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_video -lopencv_ml -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -L/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib -lIlmImf -ljasper -ltiff -lpng -ljpeg -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core -lzlib -lswscale-ffmpeg -lavutil-ffmpeg -lavformat-ffmpeg -lavcodec-ffmpeg -lgthread-2.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lglib-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -latk-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl -lstdc++

I'm getting these errors:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -ljasper
:-1: error: cannot find -ltiff
:-1: error: cannot find -ljpeg
:-1: error: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
```

**EDIT:**

In reality I'm programming for research purpose, and I m in image processing and pattern recognition, first I was on my computer doing small tests, but now I must do tests on a large database and this is very time comsuming thats why I want to use a cluster and the problem is that the cluster does'nt have opencv that's why I want to bring my .exe

To simplify things I make a small program with main only and some simple function (where figure all the header I used in my program)

headers are:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "math.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv/cv.h"
```

I put this line in my project.pro to identify the minimal dependencies :

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib   -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core
```

this works correctly but when I add the parametre :

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static
```

I have many many erros like:

```
grfmt_tiff.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler'
..
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'
..
grfmt_exr.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)'
..
grfmt_png.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
..
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `jas_cleanup'
..
system.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `pthread_spin_init'

persistence.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `gzeof'

rand.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `pthread_once'
..
(.text._ZNSt12_GLOBAL__N_13runEv+0x1d):-1: error: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
```

After installing what you tell me to install

```
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev libtiff-dev libjpeg-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

And adding this lines in my .pro

```
LIBS  += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltiff -ljpeg -lpthread -lpng -ljasper -ljbig -lz -llzma
LIBS += -L/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib -lIlmImf
```

I had dimunuate the issues to be 63 this error are like :

```
        grfmt_png.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'

        (.text+0x27a):-1: error: undefined reference to `deflateParams'
            IlmThreadMutexPosix.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_destroy'

        IlmThreadPosix.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
        ImfZipCompressor.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `compress'
        (.text+0x185e):-1: error: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
        ImfPxr24Compressor.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `compress'
        (.text._ZN12_GLOBAL__N_14pool4freeEPv.constprop.2+0x1d):-1: error: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
```

Here is the simplified code source :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "math.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>




using namespace std;


const double PI_2=atan (1.0)*2.0;
const double PI=atan (1.0)*4.0;
const double PI_4=atan (1.0);
const double PI3_4=PI_2+PI_4;
/*
void Paint_rect(){
    cv::Mat   imgq=cv::imread("/home/touka/Documents/PalmPrintProject/new-100-bmp-183-187/1_1.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cv::Mat   imgt=imgq.clone();
   cv::rectangle(imgt,cv::Point (150,150),cv::Point (874,874),CV_RGB(255,0,0),2);
    cv::imwrite("/home/touka/Desktop/test2.jpg",imgt);

}

void Save_Ort_Mat_File (cv::Mat mt, string file_name){

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (file_name.c_str());
    if(myfile){
    for (int i=0;i<mt.rows;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<mt.cols; j++)
            myfile <<setprecision(8)<< ((mt.at<double>(i,j)*180)/PI)<<" | ";
        myfile <<"\n" ;}
     myfile.close();}
    else{
        cout <<"ERROR0";
    }

}
*/
cv::Mat Sobel_Gradient_Image (cv::Mat img){
    cv::Mat  GX,GY,GXY;
    cv::Point P(-1,-1);
    cv::Vec3d   X(1,2,1);
    cv::Vec3d   Y(1,0,-1);

    cv::sepFilter2D(img,GX,img.depth(),Y,X,P,0,cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);
    cv::sepFilter2D(img,GY,img.depth(),X,Y,P,0,cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);

    vector<cv::Mat> m;
    m.push_back(GX);  m.push_back(GY);
    cv::merge(m,GXY);

    return GXY;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     cv::Mat   test;
     cv::Mat imgq=cv::imread("/home/touka/Documents/PalmPrintProject/new-100-bmp-183-187/1_1.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

   //  test= Sobel_Gradient_Image(imgq);
   // Paint_rect();
  //  Save_Ort_Mat_File(test,"file");
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

***EDIT***
Affter changing order of library and adding -pthread I finished by having only one error repeated 3 times:

```
png.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
```

I don't Know why this error is repeated 3 times Here is the new order:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core 
LIBS += -L/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib -lIlmImf 
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpng -ljasper -ltiff -ljpeg -lpthread -ljbig -llzma -pthread -lz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried adding `CONFIG += staticlib` on my project.pro but I had remarked that it's still using the dynamic library

You use this when you want to tell QMake that you are intending your build target *itself* to be a static library.  But you want a console application.  See the section with staticlib in it here in [QMake's CONFIG documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config)

> First I was using OpenCV dynamically (using an .so) But I want to execute my application on PCs that don't have OpenCV installed.

In order to replace functionality that was previously provided by a dynamic library, you will need to have all the build dependencies of that library installed (e.g. the `xxx-dev` packages whoever compiled that `.so` was using).

I'm really not sure exactly what you're building or what dependencies are legitimate or not.  It really helps if you can come up with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions.  It makes a big difference if you have a tiny program that includes OpenCV, has a `main()`, and a QMake file that tries to build it...and demonstrates your error, vs. an example others can't see or test!

But...you could try removing those `-lxxx` lines for the missing libraries and see what happens.  If you get link errors from functions which sound like they would be from those libraries, then they are *actually* needed as a dependency in your app.

But otherwise, just pushing along, you might try:

```
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev libtiff-dev libjpeg-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

Comment: I added new Informations on the post (I think this make the conversation Uncomprehensive but this was the suggestion on the reviewers

Comment: Affter changing order of library and adding -pthread I finished by having only three error :
grfmt_png.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'

I don't Know why this error is repeated 3 times

Here is the new order:

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib   -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core

LIBS += -L/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib -lIlmImf

LIBS  += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpng -ljasper -ltiff -ljpeg -lpthread  -ljbig -llzma -pthread -lz

Comment: @2K_tf Your error regarding `png_set_longjmp_fn()` is [discussed in other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21545076/211160).  It would seem the OpenCV and other libraries you are using expect libpng-1.4.x or later, but your system likely has libpng-1.2.x by default.  There are suggestions about installing the newer version in another directory in that post, if worst comes to worst you can [get it from source](https://serverfault.com/a/751831)

Comment: thnx a lot it woooorks finnally
I added: -llibpng
LIBS += -L/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib -lIlmImf -llibpng

Comment: I have a problem with reading jpg images ..It works very well with dynamic library but not now with static one 
the .bmp ones works on both modes

Comment: @2K_tf This question is already too big, so that's definitely a new question.  Continue on the track of the [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Make an example that is solely about JPEG reading, remove other dependencies...work through it step by step and see what you can do to isolate it yourself.  Is it all JPEGs, even the simplest?  Sometimes you find the source of the problem just by following a good process of forming a coherent question.

Comment: The problem is in the cv::imread it doesn't load image when they are .jpg with QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static

a simple main is:

#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::Mat img=cv::imread("/home......./1_1.jpg",0);
   cout << img.cols;
    return 0;
}
 
this return a 0 for the img.cols that mean it isn't load

Comment: @2K_tf Ask a new question, narrow it down...I'm the only person who will see your comments, and the point of StackOverflow is to put things out well phrased for everyone...if you comment just to me, then if I'm busy you won't get any help.  :)