# How do I install and use PNGwriter to write PNG image files?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I'd like to learn how to write PNG images pixel-by-pixel using both RGB and HSV color models with C++. I read that this should be fairly easy using PNGwriter (https://github.com/pngwriter/pngwriter), but I've spent many hours struggling with installing it (on Ubuntu) and compiling my code with it. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Disclaimer**: I have a weird background in the sense that I have many years of experience in using Unix-like operating systems, doing stuff in the terminal, and writing code, but I know little/nothing about installing software from the source code or compiling programs manually or with makefiles from multiple source code files.

The installation instructions on GitHub advise to do one of the following:

> **Spack:**
>
> ```
>    spack install pngwriter
>    spack load pngwriter
> ```
>
> **From Source:**
>
> First install the dependencies zlib, libpng, and (optional for text support) freetype. PNGwriter >can then be installed using CMake:
>
> ```
>    git clone https://github.com/pngwriter/pngwriter.git
>    
>    mkdir -p pngwriter-build
>    cd pngwriter-build
>    
>    # for own install prefix append: -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/somepath
>    cmake ../pngwriter
>    
>    make -j
>    
>    # optional
>    make test
>    
>    # sudo is only required for system paths
>    sudo make install
> ```

I managed to install Spack and then PNGwriter, but couldn't compile the simplest program with it and wasn't able to figure out why. I then installed PNGwriter manually, but still couldn't compile anything with it. This was many hours of struggling ago so I, unfortunately, don't remember what kind of errors or problems I was encountering at this point.

The instructions on GitHub say the following about linking:

> First set the following environment hint if PNGwriter was not installed in a system path:
>
> ```
>    # optional: only needed if installed outside of system paths
>    export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$HOME/somepath:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
> ```
>
> Use the following lines in your projects CMakeLists.txt:
>
> ```
>    find_package(PNGwriter 0.7.0)
>    
>    if(PNGwriter_FOUND)
>      target_link_libraries(YourTarget PRIVATE PNGwriter::PNGwriter)
>    endif(PNGwriter_FOUND)
> ```

**Questions**: How do I know if PNGwriter was or wasn't installed in a system path? I have `libPNGwriter.a` in `/usr/local/lib` and `pngwriter.h` in `/usr/local/include` --- does this mean that it was installed in a system path? When installing I simply tried to follow the instructions above. Do I just type the environment hint to the terminal or add it to some file? If the former then does it need to be given every time I open a new terminal session? Is "somepath" `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/include` or something else?

**Questions**: Does the second part regarding "CMakeLists.txt" depend on whether PNGwriter was installed in a system path? What is "CMakeLists.txt"? I assume it's some file one's IDE creates, but my NetBeans projects don't seem to contain such files. What if I have a single source file and compile it manually in the terminal?

Now, let's say I'd like to compile the PNGwriter quickstart example:

> ```
>    #include <pngwriter.h>
>    
>    int main()
>    {
>      int i;
>      int y;
>      pngwriter png(300, 300, 0, "test.png");
>      for(i = 1; i ≤ 300; i++)
>      {
>        y = 150 + 100*sin((double)i*9/300.0);
>        png.plot(i, y, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
>      }
>      png.close();
>      return 0;
>    }
> ```

The PNGwriter manual instructs to compile as

```
    g++ myprogram.cc -o my_program `freetype-config --cflags` -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lpng -lpngwriter -lz -lfreetype
```

but I get errors

```
    $ g++ example.cpp -o example `freetype-config --cflags` -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lpng -lpngwriter -lz -lfreetype
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'freetype2', required by 'virtual:world', not found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'freetype2', required by 'virtual:world', not found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'freetype2', required by 'virtual:world', not found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    Package 'freetype2', required by 'virtual:world', not found
    sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
    sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
    In file included from example.cpp:1:0:
    /usr/local/include/pngwriter.h:66:22: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

The answer to this Stack Overflow question ([Trying to install pygame on ubuntu which gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031260/trying-to-install-pygame-on-ubuntu-which-gives-error)) suggests to install `libfreetype6-dev`, but I apparently have the latest version already whereby the errors remain unchanged. If I instead actually add the directory containing `freetype2.pc` (I found it by going to `/` and using `find -name "freetype2.pc"`) to the environment variable (added `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `~/.bashrc` and did `source ~/.bashrc`) then I get new errors

```
    $ g++ example.cpp -o example `freetype-config --cflags` -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lpng -lpngwriter -lz -lfreetype
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpngwriter
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here I figured out that I needed to replace `-lpngwriter` with `-lPNGwriter` (i.e., the manual is erroneous). Then I get:

```
    $ g++ example.cpp -o example `freetype-config --cflags` -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lpng -lPNGwriter -lz -lfreetype
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libPNGwriter.a(pngwriter.cc.o): undefined reference to symbol 'png_set_sig_bytes@@PNG12_0'
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so: error adding     symbols: DSO missing from command line
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is where I'm currently stuck. I can't seem to find a solution by googling (at least one that I'd understand).

**Question**: How do I get this working? How do I get it working in NetBeans? Do I get these problems because I effed up the linking step above?

**Edit1**: As per john's comment, I tried swapping `-lpng` and `-lPNGwriter` and I again get new errors:

```
    $ g++ example.cpp -o example `freetype-config --cflags` -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lPNGwriter -lpng -lz -lfreetype
    /usr/local/lib/libPNGwriter.a(pngwriter.cc.o): In function `pngwriter::close()':
    pngwriter.cc:(.text+0x41c2): undefined reference to `png_convert_to_rfc1123_buffer'
    /usr/local/lib/libPNGwriter.a(pngwriter.cc.o): In function `pngwriter::read_png_info(_IO_FILE*, png_struct_def**, png_info_def**)':
    pngwriter.cc:(.text+0x4fdf): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm still left clueless.

Comment: The CMakeLists.txt file is used by cmake, which is only relevant if you are installing from source, which it seems you didn't do. So I would ignore that part.

Comment: For your final error I would try reversing the order of the libraries `-lPNGwriter -lpng` instead of the other way around.

Comment: I think I managed to do the installation both using Spack and from the source, but it's more likely that latter went wrong somehow.

Comment: @john, thanks for the suggestion, I again get new errors which I've edited into my question.

Comment: Latest issue appears to be a version conflict https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545076/libpng-png-set-longjmp-fn-not-found but I'm no expert. I would start again, and I would avoid trying to install from source. 1st choice, your normal Ubuntu package manger (e.g. apt), 2nd choice spack, 3rd choice from source.

Comment: How would I install using apt? `apt install pngwriter` gives "E: Unable to locate package pngwriter".

Comment: Only a suggestion, if it's not possible that way, you'll have to use spack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to john, I think I got it figured out. My guess is that the installation from the source (after the Spack installation) messed things up somehow. I reinstalled PNGwriter using Spack and, now apparently having all the pieces for the compilation command, was finally able to compile the example code.

**Summary**:

Source Spack

```
    # For bash/zsh/sh
    $ . spack/share/spack/setup-env.sh
    
    # For tcsh/csh
    $ source spack/share/spack/setup-env.csh
    
    # For fish
    $ . spack/share/spack/setup-env.fish
```

Install using Spack (skip if already installed)

```
    spack install pngwriter
```

Load PNGwriter (I guess one needs to do this in every new terminal session)

```
    spack load pngwriter
```

Compile (note that this isn't quite what the PNGwriter manual suggests)

```
    g++ example.cpp -o example `freetype-config --cflags` -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lPNGwriter -lpng -lz -lfreetype
```